# User defined functions variable to be accessed by rest of the other functions in python without use of classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, global-variables, web.py

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return 'hello'

    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        parse_data(data)
        display()

def parse_data(data):
    data_part=["abc","bcd"]
    return data


def display():
    data= "here i want to use the same data variable that was sent from parse_data()"



def main():
    app = web.application(URLS, globals())
    app.run()
    display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I want a variable to be accessed by rest of  the other functions in python without use of classes, How can i do that? I am trying to use a variable that is used with rest of the functions.

Comment: Which variable you want to access ?

Comment: Why don't you use parameters and `return` values? You have them in `B`, why not in `A` and `C`?

Comment: @jonrshape- i have edited the code above, i tried using return statements but that doesn't return the value

Comment: *"I have tried using return statements"* - so where are they? Did you assign the returned value(s)? Pass anything to the next function call?

Comment: What do you expect your `parse_data()` function to do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variables.

for example:

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return 'hello'

    def POST(self):
        data = web.data()
        parse_data(data)
        display()

data = "your data"

def parse_data():
    global data #only use it if you are going to edit the 'data' variable here
    data = "edit your data here"
    data_part=["abc","bcd"]



def display():
    print(data)


def main():
    #~ app = web.application(URLS, globals())
    #~ app.run()
    parse_data()
    display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

returns:

```
edit your data here
```